# Can an optional property value be null?

Tags: typescript

I thought optional properties in TypeScript covered both undefined and null cases.  Am I wrong?

If I have the following interface

```
export interface student {
   id: string;
   major?: string;
}
```

and API returns

```
{
   id: '1234',
   major: null
}
```

will this cause an error?

Comment: TypeScript won't check types at runtime.

Comment: You can run into an issue with these types since `student.major === undefined` will be `false` when the value is `null`. Can you use `major?: string | null`

Answer (score 4):

That will be incorrect, type-wise.

An optional property means that the property may either be of the type on the right (here, `string`), or it may be `undefined`.

```
interface student {
   id: string;
   major?: string;
}
```

is very similar to

```
interface student {
   id: string;
   major: string | undefined;
}
```

`null` is not included.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsCuATCA7YUC8UDeAoKBAlogFyzABOhKA5gNz4EC2AhgFYD2FA-GXFbQYBfXLgDGHFHFh8EyNJhyMoxMgHIAjACYAzABY1AGmWtOFMingAbK7iFA

(They're not exactly the same though, thanks Patrick Roberts - a type with optional property can be applied to an object which lacks the property entirely, but a required property with `| undefined` can only be applied to an object which has that property, and the value of the property may be `undefined`)

Comment: They are not equivalent. [With the second interface definition, you would not be able to declare an object literal without a `major` property.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM5gK4BMLmQbwChkTgsAuNMKUAcwG5iSBbOAKwHspL0aRbkAH2QYQOGKAhZGAX0KEEHEOjQ9MOPAF4CTZGUoByAIwAmAMwAWA4RlA)

Comment: My question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053275/why-does-ts-node-define-an-options-parameter-as-null-undefined-as-in-fs-readfi gives a good counter-example of OP, which I have yet to find a good answer. Can you take a look ?