# Why does ts-node define an options parameter as null | undefined as in fs.readFileSync?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node, node.js-fs

I am confused with fs.t.ds definition for [readFileSync](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/fs.d.ts#L2686), one of them are defined as

```
export function readFileSync(
    path: PathOrFileDescriptor,
    options?: {
        encoding?: null | undefined;
        flag?: string | undefined;
    } | null
): Buffer;
```

Why do they define the **optional property** encoding as `encoding?: null | undefined;`?

I have a function that calls `fs.readFileSync()`, how do I type my function parameter to call `fs.readFileSync`?

PS. [Difference between TypeScript optional type and type | undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371363/difference-between-typescript-optional-type-and-type-undefined) and [Can an optional property value be null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912702/can-an-optional-property-value-be-null) give me some clues but I still do not fully understand it.

Comment: `encoding?: null | undefined;` is equivalent to `encoding?: null;`, at least in modern TS (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same ), I don't know if things were ever different in the past. Does that help? *how do I type my function parameter to call fs.readFileSync?* Depends how the parameter is passed into `readFileSync`, an example (of how you want to implement it in plain JS) would help clarify

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As for my second question, I have coded `encoding: BufferEncoding` to make it work. I had thought to delete my second but since I got an answer for that I keep it. Now I am only interested in my first question, i.e. why define an optional property as type `null | undefined;` I feel `undefined` part is unnecessary. But you seem to suggest that is for historical reason  ?

Comment: That's only a guess. It may have served some point earlier (jcalz would probably know), or it may well just have been something the person who wrote this code did not even think about and just wrote `encoding?: null | undefined;`, which works and is type-safe, despite being a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`readFileSync` has multiple definition (function overloading), if you are using VSCode, you could try to click `readFileSync` while holding `Ctrl` key, and it will shows all definitions.

I guess the definition you want is:

```
export function readFileSync(
    path: PathOrFileDescriptor,
    options:
        | {
              encoding: BufferEncoding;
              flag?: string | undefined;
          }
        | BufferEncoding
): string;
```

so just type your interface like this:

```
interface FOptions {
  encoding: BufferEncoding;
  flag?: string | undefined;
}
```

---

In `FOptions` interface you provided, the `encoding` property is defined as `string`, which is widens than `BufferEncoding` (fixed string union), so the definition you want is skipped. That's why the compiler try to use the other definition

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Actually, I have figured that out. But  I still don't understand why they define an optional property as `null | undefined`.

Comment: the point of that overloading is the return type, it shows that if you didn't provide `encoding` property or it is `null`, it will return `Buffer` instead of `string`